# Trying to add each element from a for loop into an array in javascript

Tags: html, arrays, django

I have a html file index.html which displays a mySQL table:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col1</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col2</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col5</th>
       </tr>
       {% for b in obj %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    </body>
```

I want to put each value from `b.col2` & `b.col3` into separate lists. So, I'm trying to add it as follows:

```
{% for b in obj
var c1 = [];
c1.push(b.col1);
var c2 = [];
c2.push(b.col2);
%}
```

But it is not working. What is the correct way?

UPDATE:

This is my views.py:

```
def display(request):
    find_duplicate()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'obj': my_model.objects.order_by('id')})

def get_dict():
    d={}
    for e in my_model.objects.all():
        col2 = e.col2
        col3 = e.col3
        col2 = unicode(col2).encode('UTF8')
        col3 = unicode(col3).encode('UTF8')
        d.setdefault(col2, [])
        d[col2].append(col3)
    del d['']
    return d

def find_duplicate():
    #print(d)
    d = get_dict()
    for k,v in d.items():
        if len(v) > 1:
            name=[]
            id=[]
            #print(k)
            for i in v:
                #print(i)
                reg1 = i.split("(")[0]
                name.append(reg1)
                reg2 = re.search(r'[A-Z0-9]*', i.split("_")[1])
                id.append(reg2.group())
            #print(name)
            #print(id)
```

So the table looks like this:

```
Number | NameAndId
1      | Name1(something_1234)
1      | Name2(something_3456)
2      | Name3(something_7890)
2      | Name4(something_0988)
```

So the output of dictionary `d` is:

```
{'1': ['Name1(something_1234)', 'Name2(something_3456)'], '2': 'Name3(something_7890)', 'Name4(something_0988)']}
```

And then it parses the col2 in the `find_duplicate` function:

so `print(name)` in that function will give names and ids for each key `(num)` i.e., `['Name1', 'Name2']` & `['1234', '3456']` for key `1`. So, I sort of want to apply some CSS styling on the name and id part for each key. So, how to pass the results from the `find_duplicate()` function to the html?

Comment: I believe it's javascript. I got this way of displaying a table from a tutorial

Comment: that's not native javascript. Can you link to the tutorial? Edit -  it looks like it could be django? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/

Comment: I think it's Django.

Comment: @sauntimo Something like this: http://netai-nayek.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-get-database-data-in-django-view.html And the end it creates a user_page.html

Comment: @FredGandt Oh yeah of course it is, I'm taking its tutorial! But I thought this was the html javascript part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create javascript lists containing these elements, you could use this snippet to create two javascript lists containing containing the values from `b.col2` and `b.col3`

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col1</th>
                <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col2</th>
                <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col3</th>
                <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col4</th>
                <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col5</th>
            </tr>
            {% for b in obj %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.col2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.col3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.col4 }}</td>
                <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            </table>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script>
        var c2 = [], c3 = [];
        {% for b in obj %}
        c2.push("{{ b.col2 }}");
        c3.push("{{ b.col3 }}");
        {% endfor %}
        console.log([c2, c3]);
        // ... Do what you need to do in javascript with these lists.
    </script>
</body>
```